# Right or wrong way to search within XML element with XMLSearch?

Tags: xpath, coldfusion

Given the following XML:

```
<cfsavecontent variable="xml">
<root>
    <parent>
        <child>I'm the first</child>
        <child>Second</child>
        <child>3rd</child>
    </parent>
    <parent>
        <child>Only child</child>
    </parent>
    <parent>
        <child>I'm 10</child>
        <child>I'm 11!</child>
    </parent>
</root>
</cfsavecontent>
```

Is this the best way to loop over each parent and then extract all children from that parent?

```
<cfset xml = XMLParse(Trim(xml))>

<cfset parents = XMLSearch(xml, "//parent")>

<cfloop array="#parents#" index="parent">

    <cfset parent = XMLParse(parent)><!--- Is this needed? --->

    <cfset children = XMLSearch(parent, "//child")>

    <cfloop array="#children#" index="child">
        <cfoutput>#child.XmlText#</cfoutput>
    </cfloop>

</cfloop>
```

The reason I ask is because I've never been able to extract all child elements from the current XML element.

The 'Is this needed?' comment highlights the line I added to make the proceeding line work. But is it possible to to remove this line and somehow change 'XMLSearch(parent, "//child")' to only get child elements from the current 'parent'?

Thanks.

Comment: +1 -- It is indeed kind of counter-intuitive that CF does not seem to honor context in XmlSearch().

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
<cfset parent = XMLParse(parent)><!--- Is this needed? --->
```

No, it's not. It's even a performance penalty because you create a new DOM this way.

You get an array of XML nodes back from `XmlSearch()` (why else would you use `<cfloop array...`?). This means these should be equivalent:

```
<!-- new CF8 syntax -->   
<cfloop array="#parents#" index="parent">
  <cfdump var="#parent#">
</cfloop>

<!-- old syntax -->   
<cfloop from="1" to="#ArrayLen(parents)#" index="i">
  <cfdump var="#parents[i]#">
</cfloop>
```

To make ColdFusion honor context when searching a node, you need to do:

```
XMLSearch(parent, ".//child")
-------------------^
```

If you start an XPath expression with `"//"`, ColdFusion obviously searches the entire document the node belongs to, not just that node's descendants.

But if you are interested in outputting *all* `<child>` elements from the document, why not do this instead:

```
<cfset children = XMLSearch(xml, "//child")>
```

Comment: Yup, I get that, but when looping over those parent nodes I want to search within each one.

I've been unable to come up with a version of this line...

<cfset children = XMLSearch(parent, "//child")>

... so I thought, turn 'parent' from an XML Element, into an XML document and then the XPath is easier.

Comment: Sorry, commented based on your first draft.

I want all child elements, but only for the current parent.

Comment: Try to search for ".//child" in the loop. Doing "//child" obviously triggers a document-wide search, whereas starting from "." honors context.

Comment: However - looping over all parents, just to output all their children in a loop is pointless. You can select them directly, so I hope it was just an example and your app does something more than just running XmlSearch() in a nested loop. :-)

Comment: Yup, just an example. The question should have mentioned context as that's what I was wondering about. Will test is out...

Comment: Actually I was so sure that it would do what every sane person would expect that I did not even check what XMLSearch(parent, "//child") actually does. But sure enough, it gets it wrong. *sigh*

Comment: Yup, XMLSearch(parent, "//child") gets all children in the document, XMLSearch(parent, ".//child") gets children in the current parent.

Cheers Tom!